# OpenLayers map problem displaying data and interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers, geojson, cartography

I have to do a project on an application via 'openlayers'. The objective is to see on a map objects (for example a trash), if you walk and you see this object you click on it and it changes color on the application (for example it goes from green to red).
To do this I'm asked to use an 'openlayers' library and my data is in 'geojson' format.

I encounter several problems:

1. I can't read my data
2. I don't know how to code for the click on the object

Can you help me plz?

My code js:

```
var image = new CircleStyle({
 radius: 10,
 fill: new Fill({color: 'green'})
 });

var vectorPoints = new VectorLayer({
    id: 'paris',
    source: new VectorSource({
        url: '/data_v2.geojson',
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        format: new GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new Style({
        image: image
    })
   });

   var view = new View({
center: [0,0],
zoom: 2
    });

    var map = new Map({

target: 'map',
layers: [
    new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
    }),
    vectorPoints
],
view: view
    });
```

My geojson data:

> {
>       "features" : [
>           {
>               "type" : "Feature",
>               "geometry" : {
>                   "type" : "Point",
>                   "coordinates" : [0.473698,50.848808]
>               },
>               "properties" : {
>                   "ID_ELE" : 1,
>                   "ID_ETAT" : 1
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "type" : "Feature",
>               "geometry" : {
>                   "type" : "Point",
>                   "coordinates" : [0.473665,450.848177]
>               },
>               "properties" : {
>                   "ID_ELE" : 2,
>                   "ID_ETAT" : 1
>               }
>       ]
>   }

Comment: Check the [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/), especially the "select features" and "popup"

Comment: I copied paste the 3 codes of the example "select features" and the import of the file 'countries.geojson' while I downloaded their file, I didn't change anything. I don't understand why

Comment: Add the error logs if you are getting please.

Comment: The error logs: 'SCRIPT5655: SCRIPT5655: JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:1'